# how to use InstancedBufferGeometry with threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I use InstancedBufferGeometry not to show.
(when below code remove comment out, the polygon was showed.)
However i use BufferGeometry when the polygon was showed.

why below code not working.

please teach me.

```
const createGeometry = () => {
    // const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    const geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
    const positions = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(4 * 3), 3);
    const uvs = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(4 * 2), 2);

    positions.setXYZ(0, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    positions.setXYZ(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    positions.setXYZ(2, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0);
    positions.setXYZ(3, 0.5, -0.5, 1.0);
    uvs.setXYZ(0, 0.0, 0.0);
    uvs.setXYZ(1, 1.0, 0.0);
    uvs.setXYZ(2, 0.0, 1.0);
    uvs.setXYZ(3, 1.0, 1.0);
    geometry.setAttribute("position", positions);
    geometry.setAttribute("uv", uvs);

    geometry.setIndex(
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array([0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]), 1)
    );

    return geometry;
  };
```

when BufferGeometry was used.

[image]

Comment: Working with InstancedBufferGeometry involves the using of a modified material or shader material, where you manage, at least, positions of instances, and for that you'll have to have an `InstancedBufferAttribute` ([example](https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/REyzJV?editors=0010)). And to make things easier, maybe better to try `InstancedMesh`, there are several official examples: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instancing#webgl_instancing_raycast And `InstancedMesh` also supports raycasting.

Answer (score 2):

Using an `InstancedBufferGeometry` without at least a single `InstancedBufferAttribute` is not supported.

This usage does not even make sense because you want to have one or more attributes which define the variations per instance.